# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: no such label

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

I'm getting the no such android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: no such label com.yourapp.android:string/app_name when i try to use Robolectric-rc2 with and run the following test. I've tried removing the string from manifest.xml files running custom running and using build activity instead of setup activity. any ideas?

```
@RunWith(TestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
private MainActivity mainActivity;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mainActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);

}

@Test
public void textTest() throws Exception {
    TextView textView = (TextView) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.daily_text);
    assertEquals(textView, "com.yourapp.android");
    assertThat(textView).isNotNull();
}}
```

my gradle file looks like this, i've removed some of the libraries.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.robolectric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    publishNonDefault true

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourapp.android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        unitTest
        app

        def versionNumber = "1.0"

        googleFree {
            applicationId "com.yourapp.android"
            versionName versionNumber + "-googleFree"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        unitTest {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/test/java'
            }
            assets {
                srcDirs = ['src/test/assets']
            }
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.2.1'

    // Espresso
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'

    // Unit testing dependencies
    unitTestCompile('junit:junit:4.12') { // Prevent duplication conflicts
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-library'
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-integration'
    }
    unitTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'
    unitTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
    unitTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1'
    unitTestCompile 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.0.0'

    unitTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc3') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }
}

// Roboletric config
robolectric {
    // Configure includes / excludes
    include '**/*Test.class'
    include '**/*Tests.class'
    exclude '**/espresso/**/*.class'

    maxHeapSize = '2048m'

    jvmArgs '-XX:MaxPermSize=512m', '-XX:-UseSplitVerifier'

    maxParallelForks = 4

    forkEvery = 150

    ignoreFailures false

    afterTest { descriptor, result ->
        println "Executing test for ${descriptor.name} with result: ${result.resultType}"
    }
}
//end Roboletric config

// Jacoco config
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"
}

// Edit covered scope if needed
// For my part I like having the coverage of both application and tests
def coverageSourceDirs = [
        '../app/src'
]

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testUnitTestDebug") {
    group = "Reporting"

    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"

    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: '../app/build/intermediates/classes',
            excludes: ['**/R.class',
                       '**/R$*.class',
                       '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                       '**/BuildConfig.*',
                       '**/Manifest*.*']
    )

    additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData = files('../app/build/jacoco/testUnitTestDebug.exec')

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

}
//end Jacoco config

//  Start build aliases
    ...
]

def expandedTaskList = []

gradle.startParameter.taskNames.each {
    expandedTaskList << (buildAliases[it] ? buildAliases[it] : it)
}

gradle.startParameter.taskNames = expandedTaskList.flatten()

// end of build aliases

tasks.withType(Test).whenTaskAdded {
    it.systemProperty 'com.yourapp.android', android.defaultConfig.applicationId // your package name
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed this by using Robolectrci 3.0rc3 with and adding the following declaration to all my unitTest Classes

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class SomeRandomTest
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems in my project because I had different applicationId in my build flavor from the actual package. In the config attribute of your test, specify the actual package hierarchy in the package attribute.

```
@Config(sdk = 21, constants = BuildConfig.class, packageName = com.yourapp.android")
```

Also, there's no need to specify source directory for unitTest flavor. It will be picked up by default when you run your test case. Just specify the asset directory. Try this code:

```
productFlavors {
    unitTest {
        sourceSets.main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/test/assets']
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will build all the resources from your main folder for your unitTest flavor.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like changing in your AndroidManifest file the following line does the trick from

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

to

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="com.yourapp.android" >
```

Additionally default configuration section in gradle file can be commented out like so.

```
    defaultConfig {
   // applicationId "com.yourapp.android"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
```